# Hide rows based on offset value

Tags: excel, vba

I've a problem hiding rows based on other row's value.

I've tried to do some `For Next` loops and `c.offsets`, but can't target the right rows.

Original structure:
[image]

Desired structure:
[image]

I want to hide the rows that only contain the subtitles or is completely blank, but keep the titles.

Comment: Are there rows containing something else than "Sub title"? I mean, checking only for empty cells or "Sub title" in column A:A should be enough...

Comment: They actually do have a number value connected to them

Comment: So, the code must check if in A:A "Sub title" string exists and hide the row only if not any other string exist on it. Is this understanding correct? Now, I suppose that in case of empty cell in A:A, no other records appear on the row. Is this supposition correct, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hide Rows

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub hideEmptyAndSub()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const cCol As String = "A"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 1
    Const Crit As String = "*Sub title*"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, cCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim hrg As Range
    Dim hcell As Range
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = FirstRow To LastRow
        Set hcell = ws.Cells(i, cCol)
        cValue = CStr(hcell.Value)
        If Len(cValue) = 0 Or UCase(cValue) Like UCase(Crit) Then
            If hrg Is Nothing Then
                Set hrg = hcell
            Else
                Set hrg = Union(hrg, hcell)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    If Not hrg Is Nothing Then
        hrg.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @VBasic2008  - The string "Sub title" is supposed to hide every row containing a subtitle, but there are 20 different named subtitles, that occasionally changes. Can I just ad more constants?

Comment: Instead of `Const Crit As String = "*Sub title*"` use `Dim Crit As Variant: Crit = Array("TitleThis", "TitleThat", "Add more")` and replace `If Len(cValue) = 0 Or UCase(cValue) Like UCase(Crit) Then` with `If Len(cValue) = 0 Or IsNumeric(Application.Match(cValue, Crit, 0) Then`.

Comment: Note that in my previous comment the closing parenthesis of `IsNumeric` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please. It will hide the rows having a blank cell in column A:A and the ones having "Sub title" in A:A and nothing else in the following cells:

```
Sub testHiddingSubTtlRows()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastCol As Long, arrA, i As Long, rngH As Range, boolH As Boolean
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet  'use here your necessary sheet
 lastCol = sh.UsedRange.Columns.count  'last column
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row (in A:A)
 arrA = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastR).value 'put the range in an array (for speed)
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrA)
    boolH = False 
    If arrA(i, 1) = "Sub title" Then
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("B" & i, sh.cells(i, lastCol))) = 0 Then boolH = True
    ElseIf arrA(i, 1) = "" Then
        boolH = True
    End If
    If boolH Then
        If rngH Is Nothing Then
            Set rngH = sh.Range("A" & i)
        Else
            Set rngH = Union(rngH, sh.Range("A" & i))
        End If
    End If
 Next i
 If Not rngH Is Nothing Then rngH.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

The code should be very fast, building a `Union` range for the matching criteria cells and hiding the rows at once, at the end of the code.

Please, test it and send some feedback.

**Edited**:

Please, test the next adapted code, able to hide any sub titles, without previously keeping them somehow (in an array, collection, dictionary etc.):

```
Sub testHiddingSubTtlRows()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastCol As Long, arrA, i As Long, rngH As Range, boolH As Boolean, boolT As Boolean
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastCol = sh.UsedRange.Columns.count
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 arrA = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastR).value
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrA)
    boolH = False: boolT = False
    If arrA(i, 1) = "Title" Then
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("B" & i + 1, sh.cells(i + 1, lastCol))) = 0 Then boolH = True: boolT = True
    ElseIf arrA(i, 1) = "" Then
        boolH = True
    End If
    If boolH Then
        If rngH Is Nothing Then
            Set rngH = sh.Range("A" & IIf(boolT, i + 1, i))
        Else
            Set rngH = Union(rngH, sh.Range("A" & IIf(boolT, i + 1, i)))
        End If
    End If
 Next i
 If Not rngH Is Nothing Then rngH.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank FaneDuru! I see you have out a lot of work into this! I really appreciate it! It works :)  I don't know if I expressed my self inaccurate, but i would like it to hide the "Sub title" rows as well, but in a more general manner, as I have approx. 1500 with 20 different subtitles

Comment: @Svend2000: I am afraid that "in a more general manner" it is something without too much meaning. I clearly asked and then explained what the code does. What else would you like it doing? What algorithm to be taken in consideration by the code? So, don't you have there "Sub title"? Do you have some other strings? would they be identified like something following after "Title"?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I have 20 something subtitles, that is occasionally changing. I would like the code to hide those,  subtitles, regardless of their name. The subtitles is always on row beneath the title (which always is below a blank row)

Comment: OK. I will adapt the code to work for **any** such a string, if it appears beneath the "Title". No  need to keep track of the Sub titles strings...